# How to update the list item from grid(custom web part)

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, development, csom, sharepoint-on-prem

I have one list.in that list title column,Start date ,Due DAte ,Assigned To,Status column is there.And some entries also there.All the list items i am displaying in one grid.After that in that grid Status column i need to change as editable.Aftet that one button is there named as save.On click of save that particular row should change in list also.For example in Particular row status column i am changing as completed then in list also it should update as completed.Just imagine i have 3 rows.3 rows i edited the status as completed.After click save button in list also 3 rows should change as completed.

if login name =assigned to person then that particular row i am displaying in grid through c#.After that i tried to edit in the grid the from dropdown status column as completed.I have save button also.but i don't know how to update that in list.Is it possible? Because as far as i know in event receiver only i can update the list item.But i am trying in Custom web part.If it is possible Can u give c# code?

Comment: It’s pretty hard to understand what you are asking. Can you add screenshots, schemas, flows?

Comment: In my sharepoint site i have one list.In that list i have some list items.all the items i am displaying in grid(custom web part).In that grid one column i have to edit.And that editable value i should update in my list item.I can't add screen shot.My organization is not allowed to use internet.In my home only i am using internet.I need result immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Using ASP.net: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/edit-and-update-record-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net/

First, you need to add an `EditItemTemplate` in the `TemplateField` that specifies a custom user interface (UI) for the item in edit mode then `RowUpdating` to update the list. Try this sample code, replace `YourDbContext` with the name of your `DbContext`, and `YourList` with the name of your list. Also, replace `DropDownList1` with the ID of your DropDownList. Try and let me know if this works for you.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the new values from the GridView row
    string newStatus = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList1")).SelectedValue;

    // Get the ID of the item to update
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

    // Use Entity Framework to update the database
    using (YourDbContext db = new YourDbContext())
    {
        // Find the item in the database using the ID
        var item = db.YourList.Find(id);

        // Update the status
        item.Status = newStatus;

        // Save the changes to the database
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    // Rebind the GridView to show the changes
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```